# PostgreSQL how to treat null as a value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-in, sql-null

Let us say:

1. I have a table with the name "movie" and it contains a field with the name "categoryid" which points to another "category" table.
2. The field "categoryid" can be null in case no category was selected for a movie. Otherwise it's a number.
3. I have a user interface for a movies search page, that lists all categories in the form of a list of checkboxes so the user can select multiple categories. And this list of checkboxes also includes an "Uncategorised" option to select movies where "categoryid" is null

Now the user is now selecting null and multiple other checkboxes, this reflects into an SQL code that would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM movie WHERE categoryid in (1, 5, 9, NULL);
```

Apparently, the above code doesn't work. I guess null is not treated as a value is SQL like it is in other languages! Uncategorized movies were filtered out. The below code works however

```
SELECT * FROM movie WHERE categoryid IN (1, 5, 9) OR categoryid IS NULL;
```

But unfortunately, the framework I work with can't make this exception, and I have no flexibility over the structure of the database as it's generated by another software. So, is there any way I can use the NULL value with the IN operator? or any other operator that will accept a list of allowed values?

Comment: Unlike programming languages the SQL Standard defines "null" as a placeholder for a value. It represents a "value that does exist but is currently missing".

Comment: What does your framework allow?  This is trivial to handle in SQL but it is not clear what you *can* do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is *not* to use NULL for this. NULL works best if you interpret it as “unknown”, but in your case the value is known: it is “uncategorized”.

So it would be best if you create a special category for that and handle it like all others. Don't allow NULLs here, and everything becomes simple.

Alternatively, you can replace NULL with a value that doesn't otherwise exist in the query using something like

```
coalesce(category, '')
```

That would create the “uncategorized” category on the fly.

Comment: I totally agree with you! Unfortunately, the database I'm working with was generated by another software and I can't change anything in its structure.

Comment: But I didn't know about the **coalesce** function it solved my problem! :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

`IN` does not work with `NULL` values unfortunately. An alternative would be to put the values in a derived table, and use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`:

```
select m.*
from movie m
inner join (values (1), (5), (9), (null)) v(val) 
    on v.val is not distinct from m.category_id
```

It might be more convenient for your application to pass the list of values as an array:

```
select m.*
from movie m
inner join unnest(array[1, 5, 9, null]) v(val)
    on v.val is not distinct from m.category_id
```

Comment: Ok I'll try this. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

Another approach, with same results would be:

```
SELECT * FROM movie WHERE zeroifnull(categoryid) in (1, 5, 9, 0);
```

The idea behind is previously transform your NULL value to another value (zero in this case).

You can also use IFNULL().

Comment: What SQL server supports this zeroifnull function? I'm using postgreSQL and it says *function zeroifnull(bigint) does not exist *